# How to clear all Log files data using Monolog in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, logfiles

How to empty log files data before adding new contents to it. 
Using Monolog for saving all logs inside

> storage/app/logs/*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rm` command through ssh to remove all logs:

`rm storage/logs/laravel-*.log`. Use `*` as wildcard to remove all logs if they have suffixes.

Or you can add custom code within Controller method only for admins of app:

```
 $files = glob('storage/logs/laravel*.log');

        foreach($files as $file){
            if(file_exists($file)){
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
```

Or create a console command. Depending on version, below 5.3 use for example:

`php artisan make:console logsClear --command=logs:clear`

For versions 5.3 and above

`php artisan make:command logsClear`

add signature within command class if it doesn't exist.

`protected $signature = 'logs:clear';`

Add your class in Console/Kernel.php, in protected $commands array ( note that your code varies upon customization for your app):

```
<?php

    namespace App\Console;


    use App\Console\Commands\logsClear;
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    use App\Utils\ShareHelper;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [


            logsClear::class,

        ];

        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {

        }
    }
```

You should add then custom code in `handle()` of logsClear class

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class logsClear extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'logs:clear';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $files = glob('storage/logs/laravel*.log');

        foreach($files as $file){
            if(file_exists($file)){
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `php artisan logs:clear` command

Comment: Why do you check file existance?

Comment: symlinks maybe ?